# koa2 ctx.render can't render in a function

Tags: koa2

I want to render docs to list page, but in the browser, list page is not found.

This is the code:

```
router.get('/', function(ctx){
    let type = getURLParm(ctx.url).type;
    var article = {};
    var content = {};
    mongoService.find('col', { type: type, id: { $gte: 0 } },
     function(docs) {
       ctx.render('list',{data:docs});
    });        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Koa (unlike Express) does not wait for any callbacks, so, if the function ended, and the response body is empty, then the request will return Not Found.

To do the trick you must promisify your mongoService.find function, write the middleware as an async function, then await for the mongoService.find

Code for Koa2:

```
router.get('/', async function(ctx){
  let type = getURLParm(ctx.url).type;
  var article = {};
  var content = {};
  let docs = await mongoService.find('col', { type: type, id: { $gte: 0 } })
  ctx.render('list',{data:docs});       
});
```

And one advice: use a library to parse the request data, for example [koa-body](https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-body)